# Apache mod_mem_cache vary-deflate buq FIx but need rewrite rule advice

Tags: apache, caching, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

IF query string ?g and type css or js - gzip-deflate disabled

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js)$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^g$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSA,E=no-gzip:1,PT,L]
```

**If no gzip suport by user agent redirecto to file witch query string ?g eq. style.css?g**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(css|js)$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} !^gzip\,deflate$

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^g$

RewriteRule "^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\.(css|js)$" $1.$2?g [R=301]
```

My problem is that for 301 need to rel path but go to default dir

```
http:// localhost/style/style.js -> http://d:\some\path/style.js?g

http:// localhost/js/e.js -> http://d:\some\path/e.js?g
```

To fix that i think need to know real path eq

```
RewriteRule "^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\.(css|js)$" http://%{HOST}/%{PATH}/$1.$2?g [R=301]
```

But i dont know how do name this

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule "^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\.(css|js)$" http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?g [R=301]`